# Symfony: Wrong firewall used when session expires

Tags: php, session, symfony, firewall

I have a Symfony app which used FOSUserBundle (not sure that matters as it's an issue with the Firewall). It has 2 firewalls, both for different sections of the site. One is the front end and the other an admin area.

The issue I'm having is that when the user logs in to the front end and after their session expires (if they didn't choose to remember login), they are redirected to the admin firewall logout target.

Here's the firewall configuration in my security file:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_CLIENT:          ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ACCOUNT_MANAGER: ROLE_CLIENT
    ROLE_DESIGNER:        ROLE_USER
    ROLE_PUBLISHER:       ROLE_DESIGNER
    ROLE_ADMIN:           [ROLE_PUBLISHER, ROLE_ACCOUNT_MANAGER]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:     [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

firewalls:
    site:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: site_survey_launch
            login_path: site_login
            check_path: site_login_check
            use_referer: true
            success_handler: xd_authentication.event.listener
        logout:
            path: site_logout
            target: site_login
            success_handler: xd_authentication.event.listener
        anonymous: true
    portal:
        pattern: ^/portal
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: portal_user_surveys_live
            login_path: portal_login
            check_path: portal_login_check
        logout:
            path: portal_logout
            target: portal_login
        anonymous: true
        context: shared
acl:
    connection: default
```

The success_handler handler for the site logout configuration returns a redirect response for site_login. Even more reason to be fairly confused about this issue. Unless the success_handler is only used for a manual logout process.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to figure out what's going on for a few months now.

Answer (score 0):

I think that order of firewall definitions is important, because `site` has pattern `^/` and I think that it processing request from `^/portal` url. You should define `portal` firewall before `site` firewall.

Comment: That's how it was originally. I swapped them round earlier this morning to see if it was related to the order. Just changed it back and tried again and it's still happening. Thanks for the input though.